# Архитектура приложений в Unity3d

Tags: unity3d, архитектура, чистый-код

Всем доброго дня/вечера!

Возможно ли в Unity применять MVC, или есть смысл посмотреть на другие варианты?

Что касаемо MVC то, хорошая ли практика вешать на один объект 2 скрипта (1 скрипт отвечает за модель, 2 отвечает за UI)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочитали книги — идите фигачить код. Появятся конкретные вопросы — зададите. Вопрос "хорошая практика на объект вешать 2 объекта" более конкретный, чем текущий, но нужно пояснить хорошим примером — да и ответы будут скорее всего будут [примерно такие](https://bash.im/quote/438821): "так как вы не описали где применять, то в некоторых случаях это будет хорошей практикой, иногда нет".

Книги "чистый код" вам за глаза хватит на несколько лет вперёд, если будете писать код и применять полученные знания; но вы хотите потратить ближайшие пять на поиск серебряной пули (которой нет), это глупо.

Для начала попробуйте построить самую классическую, простую трёхуровневую архитектуру. Начинайте с бизнес-логики, это самая главная часть, к которой постепенно пристыковывайте остальное. Хороший пример приложения разобран на хабре ([тынц](https://habr.com/post/322258/)), исходники выложены в git.

Если у вас не возникнет вопросов и трёхзвенка вас всем устроила — <s>это плохо</s> значит вы уже нашли наиболее подходящую архитектурную форму и можете пользоваться ей в подобных приложениях. Если возникнут конкретные вопросы — задавайте их, метки архитектура и инспекция кода на so ваши помощники. Если появится понимание, что архитектура не особо подходит начнёте поиски более подходящей под новые требования.